# Fetching latest records in Batch mode - Apache Seatunnel

Tags: mysql, batch-processing, data-synchronization

I have successfully deployed Seatunnel in my system. I'm currently working on synchronizing data between the source and sink in MySQL. I'm running Seatunnel in batch mode, but it's currently retrieving all records from the source and dumping them into the sink table. I need to run this job every 30 minutes, but it should only fetch the latest records from the source, not all the records.

Is there a way to configure Seatunnel to only retrieve the latest records from the source and dump them into the sink table in batch mode?